# JavaScript error (Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input)

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax, syntax-error, indentation

I have some JavaScript code that works in FireFox but not in Chrome or IE.

In the Chrome JS Console I get the follow error:

> "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input".

The JavaScript code I am using is:

```
<script>
 $(function() {
 $("#mewlyDiagnosed").hover(function() {
    $("#mewlyDiagnosed").animate({'height': '237px', 'top': "-75px"});
 }, function() {
    $("#mewlyDiagnosed").animate({'height': '162px', 'top': "0px"});
 });
</script>
```

It says the error is on the last line which is `});`

Comment: I know that Chrome's V8, for a `DELETE` on the server if the response was a 200 `success` instead of a [204](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-10.2.5) `success - no response` I would get this error as well. Just heads up in case anyone is getting this as well.

Answer (score 472, accepted):

Add a second `});`.

When properly indented, your code reads

```
$(function() {
    $("#mewlyDiagnosed").hover(function() {
        $("#mewlyDiagnosed").animate({'height': '237px', 'top': "-75px"});
    }, function() {
        $("#mewlyDiagnosed").animate({'height': '162px', 'top': "0px"});
    });
MISSING!
```

You never closed the outer `$(function() {`.

Comment: The lesson is, **always indent your code** (and indent it correctly).

Comment: The lesson is, always use good editor with good plugins, which can detect parentheses pairing, highlight it or even repair problems.

Comment: @HeyWatchThis You might try Syntastic for Vim.

Comment: I use neomake for vim/neovim, configured to run jshint every time I save a JavaScript file. If I have syntax errors, I'll see warning/error symbols in vim's/neovim's gutter. When I put my cursor on that line, the vim/neovim command line will show a message saying what the error is.

Comment: Wonder how it could have possibly "worked in Firefox"... :-/

Answer (score 100):

In my case, I was trying to parse an empty JSON:

```
JSON.parse(stringifiedJSON);
```

In other words, what happened was the following:

```
JSON.parse("");
```

Comment: This, unfortunatly, includes `$.parseJSON` of jquery 1.11.2

Answer (score 40):

http://jsbeautifier.org/ is helpful to indent your minified JS code.

Also, with **Google Chrome** you can use "pretty print". See the example screenshot below showing `jquery.min.js` from Stack Overflow nicely indented right from my browser :)

[image]

Answer (score 16):

Formatting your code a bit, you have only closed the inner hover function.  You have not closed the outer parts, marked below:

```
$(// missing closing)
 function() { // missing closing }
     $("#mewlyDiagnosed").hover(
        function() {
            $("#mewlyDiagnosed").animate({'height': '237px', 'top': "-75px"});
        }, 
        function() {
            $("#mewlyDiagnosed").animate({'height': '162px', 'top': "0px"});
        });
```

Answer (score 12):

In my case, it was caused by a missing `(0)` in `javascript:void(0)` in an anchor.

Comment: Same issue:  but, I had `javascript:void(0` missing a `)`

Answer (score 7):

In my case, it ended up being a **simple double quote** issue in my **bookmarklet**, remember only use single quotes on bookmarklets. Just in case this helps someone.

Comment: Thank you so much, I was totally confused about why my bookmarklet is not working. Now it seems to work! Any specific reason, why double quotes aren't accepted in bookmarklets?

Answer (score 6):

This error is mainly caused by empty returned ajax calls, when trying to parse an empty JSON.

To solve this test if the returned data is empty

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "get",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) {

        if(response.data.length == 0){
            // EMPTY
        }else{
            var obj =jQuery.parseJSON(response.data);
            console.log(obj);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I got this error when I was trying to write a javascript bookmarklet. I couldn't figure out what was causing it. But eventually I tried URL encoding the bookmarklet, via the following website: http://mrcoles.com/bookmarklet/ and then the error went away, so it must have been a problem with certain characters in the javascript code being interpreted as special URL control characters.

Comment: I had a // comment in my js, which commented out a bit more than I wanted since pasting it into the url of the bookmarklet made the whole code a one-liner and the // was in the middle of the code.

Comment: Removing comments fixed it for me as well.

Answer (score 1):

I got this since I had a comment in a file I was adding to my JS, really awkward reason to what was going on - though when clicking on the `VM` file that's pre-rendered and catches the error, you'll find out what exactly the error was, in my case it was simply uncommenting some code I was using.

Comment: I had the same issue, sometimes ftp transfer mess up file's lines, and single line comments may include afterward lines in their line

Answer (score 1):

I also got this error pointing to the end of the last script block on a page, only to realize the error was actually from clicking on an element with a `onclick="pagename"` instead of `onclick="window.location='pagename'"`. It's not always a missing bracket!

Answer (score 1):

I think it could be almost any javascript error/typing error in your application.
I tried to delete one file content after another and finally found the typing error.

Comment: I am getting this error on the second and sunsequent calls. The first call works fine but thereafter i get the error and it points to line one of the html. Unhelpful.
I wrote a program to check all brces, brackets and quotes and all are balanced.

The code is quite complex maybe - and there is a lot of it.
Any other ideas please?