# Error on external jquery js script when uploaded to a server

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have my test site doing well on my localhost but when I try to upload it on some free hosting server my firebug says something like these.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input jquery.js:3
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function bootstrap.min.js:6
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined bootstrap-tooltip.js:252
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input ckeditor.js:57
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined jquery.fancybox.pack.js:45
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

Why is that happening?

Comment: Either your upload failed or the server is not serving the files correctly.

Comment: I've upload the files successfully.

Comment: Is it because of the server?

Comment: If you open `//yourserverhere/jquery.js` directly in the browser is it complete?

Comment: Wow, I checked it and compared it to my localhost. The file is cut down. Why is that?

Comment: Download the file from the ftp (if you have access) and compare to the original. If the file is alright, then the server is not serving it correctly, exactly as Firebug tells you - the server stops serving it before the EOF causing the "Unexpected end" loading error.

Comment: Yeah you're right, the file is not complete. I just contacted to the support. I'm waiting for the reply. Thanks! :D

Answer (score 0):

The 3 most common causes for the `Unexpected end` error in my experience:

1. The file upload was not completed successfully. Even though some tools like FileZilla may give a successful message, it does not necessarily mean that the server stored the file correctly. Better to download the file back and check against the original to be sure.
2. Malfunctioning/badly configured servers may cut up the response or error out before serving the whole file.
3. You may have a syntax error in your JS. (for example [an unmatched brace will thrown this error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3983088/1331430)).

As you can see, #3 is the actual reason why the error is thrown, while #1 and #2 will cause it to happen.