# Can't access JSON object array

Tags: javascript, json, data-structures

I have the following JSON object (accessed through `item`):

[image]

I don't know why this is stumping me, but to access the values of `divisions`, I would do either `item.divisions` or `item["divisions"]`, right? I'm getting `undefined` when I try both of those options. What's going on? Am I not accessing the data correctly?

Aaand, here it is:

```
//options has information like hostname, path, etc.
var req = https.request(options, function(res) {
  res.setEncoding('utf8');
  res.on('data', function (item) {
    console.log(item); //this is the JSON that you're seeing
    console.log(item.kind); //undefined
  });
});
```

Comment: Check if that is actual JSON or string

Comment: Are you sure that the `divisions` variable is actually defined and contains data?

Comment: validate your JSON first, is it correct?

Comment: please paste the json instead of snapshot

Comment: Show us your code

Comment: @homerboy Unless you show us how you have loaded the JSON to your variable, we wont be able to help you. As simple as that.

Comment: @RajaAnbazhagan there you go.

Comment: You need to call `JSON.parse()` to convert the JSON into an object.

Answer (score 3):

You need to parse the JSON into a Javascript object.

```
//options has information like hostname, path, etc.
var req = https.request(options, function(res) {
  res.setEncoding('utf8');
  res.on('data', function (response) {
    console.log(response); //this is the JSON that you're seeing
    item = JSON.parse(response);
    console.log(item.kind);
  });
});
```

Comment: I'm receiving an `SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input` and I think it's because I'm parsing an empty JSON: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3983088/javascript-error-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-end-of-input (2nd answer)

Comment: If `console.log(response)` shows the JSON that you posted, then it's not empty JSON.

Comment: It isn't an empty JSON, but when I parse it, the JSON stops halfway and throws the error. `typeof response` is showing up as string.

Comment: jsonlint.com says the JSON is valid.

Comment: I'd show you the screenshot of my terminal but I have no idea how to send that through the comments.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125577/discussion-between-homerboy-and-barmar).

Comment: Don't post screenshots, copy and paste plain text into the question. Mark it as code with the `{}` tool in the SO editor.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem can be solved like this ,

```
var x = "YOUR JSON"
```

**x.divisions** gives you the object

```
Object {ocd-division/country:us/state:me/sldl:141: Object, ocd-division/country:us: Object, ocd-division/country:us/state:me/county:washington/council_district:1: Object, ocd-division/country:us/state:me/cd:2: Object, ocd-division/country:us/state:me/place:princeton: Object…}
```

Your key has **string** and your value is **Object**

You can further access it like

```
var p = x.divisions

 for (var key in p) {
  if (p.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    console.log(key + " -> " + p[key]);
  }
}
```

Hope it helps !!