# Syntax error with my PHP script

Tags: javascript, alert, sweetalert

I'm running into an error which reads as follow in the console of my Google Chrome browser:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Below is my code:

```
/*=====  Login Alert  ======*/

function loginAlert() {
    swal({   
        title: "Login Required",   
        type: 'error',
        text: "Please <a href='/login'>login</a> first to submit your ticket.",   
        html: true,
    });
}
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I resolve it?

Comment: You have a `,` at the end there, shouldn't be there. Also, this looks like javascript to me? So, your problem might be somewhere else, as your error is indeed within `php`.

Comment: @Nytrix Re: the comma, read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Trailing_commas

Answer (score 0):

This is what you should be doing.

Take a look at the snippet below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#loginBtn").on("click", function() {
    swal({
      title: 'Login Required',
      type: 'error',
      text: 'Please <a href="login">login</a> first to submit your ticket.',
      html: true,
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<button id="loginBtn">Login Test</button>
```

---

The `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input` error you have indicates that you have an improperly terminated function or statement.

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3983103/6381711) for more details and resolution; you should consider going through your code as the actual error must be somewhere else.