# CORS "SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input at" with fetch API vs PHP

Tags: javascript, php, http-headers, apache2, fetch

```
/*
* @version: 1.0.0
* @author: Murod Parmonov
* @licence: MIT
*/

class HTTP{


    // post request
    post(url, data){
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                fetch(url, {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-type': 'application/json'
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify(data),
                    'mode': 'no-cors'
                }).
                **then(response => response.json()).then(data => resolve(data)).
                catch(err => reject(err));**
            }
        );
    }



}

const ht = new HTTP;  // http  fetch API class
ht.post('https://correctserverurl.com/', data).then(resData => console.log(resData))    .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

[error I got from the server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zarI.png)
the noted with double stars line in js code is the line error.

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: correctdomain.com');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers:  X-Requested-With");

$ping = file_get_contents("php://input");
file_put_contents('ping.json', $ping);
$ping = json_decode($ping, 1);
echo json_encode($data = [
    'status' => 'success'
]);
```

I included whole class of fetch API even I think it is unneccessary.
I think I provide every detail needed.
I ensured that the code works on others server but only on my server something is wrong.
what am I doing wrong here?
what should I do to solve the problem?

Comment: The error is in your http.js script. Post it including the referenced line 29, and as `text`, *not as image*.

Comment: Please go read [ask]. Code relevant to your problem belongs directly into your question, in text form and properly formatted. DO NOT just show _images of code_.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript error (Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3983088/javascript-error-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-end-of-input)

Comment: Please add the entire script to your question.

Comment: php script or js?

Comment: take a look now! please.

Comment: You are trying to debug both ends of a communication channel simultaneously. Try doing one at a time.

Comment: @symcbean I'm not aware of that things deeper as expected. can you tell me what to change to what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-PINGOTHER, Content-Type');`
actually, this was worth to do a little bit research. 
the magic line helped me to solve the the same problem.