# SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input in fetch API

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, redirect, fetch

I face a new problem that has been asked before in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3983088/javascript-error-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-end-of-input). But It is not relevant to my problem.

What I have implemented is a very simple API using `nodejs`, `express-framework` and `mongoose`. 
The problem is with fetch API. I want to submit some ID and post it to the server. In the server side I redirect it to the proper URL base on the ID that user entered. Whenever I test this part, this error is being raised in front-end side and points to `return response.json()` line.

> SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Here is my code:

**Front-End:**

```
function submitCode(){
    var nationalCode = document.getElementById('nationalCode').value
    var data = {
        nationalCode: nationalCode,
        creationDate: new Date().toLocaleDateString()
    }

    fetch('/submit', {
        method: 'POST',
        redirect:'manual',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
    },
    ).then(response => {
        return response.json()
    }).then(jsonData => {
        console.log('success:', jsonData)
        history.pushState(null, null, "/lashkhor")
    }).catch(e => {
        console.log('error:', e)
        return e
    })
}
```

**Back-End:**

```
app.post('/submit', (req, res) => {
    var nationalCode = req.body.nationalCode
    var creationDate = req.body.creationDate

    query = {'nationalCode': nationalCode}
    nationalCodeModel.find(query, (err, success) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log('error:', err)
        }
        else if (success.length == 0){
            nationalCodeModel.create({
                nationalCode: nationalCode,
                creationDate: creationDate
            })
            console.log('salam khoshgele daei!')
            res.redirect('/khoshgeledaei')
        }
        else if (success.length > 0) {
            console.log('lashkhor detected')
            res.redirect('/lashkhor')
        }
    })

})

app.get('/lashkhor', (req, res) => {
    console.log('here')
    res.send('salam')
})
```

I can't find any hint to solve it. I would be thankful if anyone could help me.

**PS:** Whole code is available in [this repository](https://github.com/mostafaghadimi/mask_donation)

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the whole error message with the stack trace?

Comment: @ArunKumarMohan That's all. `error: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
    at (index):26`. I have put the repository link in the post.

Comment: What about the stack trace? Knowing the line on which the code fails will help.

Comment: at this line in UI: `return response.json()`

Comment: Also: Do you see this error in the backend or frontend?

Comment: @geekonaut front-end (chrome console)

Comment: Can you check the network tab and share the response coming from the server?

Comment: @geekonaut Sure! I will edit the post in 2 minutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to parse text into json.
You can use `res.json()` instead of `res.send()` from your backend.

Comment: In your frontend:
`.then(response => {
        return response.json()
    })`

response.json fails because the response from the server is not JSON.