# Why my micro-API does not have response body?

Tags: javascript, api, perl, cgi, fetch-api

For my little Javascript app I wrote serverside API function with [CGI](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI).

I made it very simple, and full example script looks like that:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict; use warnings; use 5.014; 

use CGI;
use JSON;
use Data::Dumper;

my $q = new CGI;
my %p = $q->Vars;

_api_response();

sub _api_response {
  my ( $error ) = @_;
  my $res;

  my $status = 200;
  my $type = 'application/json';
  my $charset = 'utf-8';

  if ( $error ) {
    $status = 500;
    $res->{data} = {
      status => 500,
    };
    $res->{error} = {
        error => 'failure',
        message => $error,
        detail => Dumper \%p,
    };
  } else {
    $res->{data} = {
      status => 200,
    };
  }

  print $q->header( 
    -status   => $status, 
    -type     => $type,
    -charset  => $charset,
  );

  my $body = encode_json( $res );
  print $body;
}
```

When I call it from JS script with `fetch`, it gets no response body. If I checked from Developers Tools/Network, it has also no response body. If I enter the same URL into browser, it shows JSON body. If I use `curl` as

```
curl -v 'https://example.com/my_api?api=1;test=2;id=32'
```

response seems have also correct body:

```
< HTTP/2 200 
< date: Mon, 13 Sep 2021 14:04:42 GMT
< server: Apache/2.4.25 (Debian)
< set-cookie: example=80b7b276.5cbe0f250c6c7; path=/; expires=Thu, 08-Sep-22 14:04:42 GMT
< cache-control: max-age=0, no-store
< content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< 
* Connection #0 to host example.com left intact
{"data":{"status":200}}
```

Why `fetch` does not see it as a body?

For sake of completeness, I include JS part also:

```
async function saveData(url = '', data = {}) {
  const response = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'GET', 
    mode: 'no-cors', 
    cache: 'no-cache', 
    credentials: 'omit',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    redirect: 'follow', 
    referrerPolicy: 'no-referrer', 
  });
  console.log(response); // body is null
  return response.json(); 
}
```

Using the function as:

```
saveData('https://example.com/my_api?api=1;test=2;id=32', { answer: 42 })
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data);
  })
  .catch( error => {
    console.error( error );
  });
```

On console I see error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
```

One possible reason for this error is empty JSON string.

Comment: Why do you have a `content-type` header in `fetch`?  This header specifies the content type of the request body, but there is no request body since it is a GET request. For signaling to the server what kind of content you accept the `Accept` header should be used. Note also that you don't send this header in your `curl` command, so this header might actually be the problem.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich `content-type` was clearly unneccessary, but omitting it made no change.

Comment: Have you done any debugging on the Perl side? What do you see in your server log?

Comment: You did not demonstrate how `my_api` calls `_api_response`.

Comment: @PolarBear I modified my example to fully functional script, with calling the function.

Comment: @simbabque Server logs show accessing, but nothing out of order for my eye... I don't see any significant difference in %ENV-s in different calls .

Comment: You call `_api_response()` without any arguments. `_api_response(@args)` expects some arguments, if arguments are not provided then you end up with `print $q->header(...)` and `print $body` where body is `json { status => 200 }` (exactly what request from web browser receives). It looks like your problem is in JavaScript, for debug purpose add in Perl code verification block which dumps received data into a file for a study what could be a cause of the issue.

Comment: I can reproduce your problem with the code you've shown.

Comment: Check your js again, error does not look like runtime one. Ie. https://stackoverflow.com/a/3983103/223226

Comment: Also check the network tab in the browser console.

Comment: @mpapec all I see on console is `test__bootstrap_modal.html:143 SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input at saveData (test__bootstrap_modal.html:196)`. And as I mentioned in OP, the Network tab is on same tune with `fetch`: there is no response body. I tried also with Postman and it shows correct JSON body as response

Comment: Does error appear immediately or on fetch execution?

Comment: @mpapec on fetch execution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to reproduce your problem, and then I was able to fix it.

It was a CORS issue. You need to enable CORS on both the front and the back end.

On the front end you need to set the content security policy with a meta tag in your page's `<head>`:

```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' http://localhost">
```

(Don't forget to change `localhost` to whatever your real domain is.)

On the back you need to add the CORs header:

```perl
  print $q->header( 
    -status   => $status, 
    -type     => $type,
    -charset  => $charset,
    -access_control_allow_origin => '*', # <-- add this line
  );
```

As a side note, none of the settings you're passing into `fetch` are necessary. And since you're awaiting the response and then returning another promise anyway, there is really no reason for that to even be a an async function.

Until you're ready to do something with the unused `data` argument, the following code will suffice:

```js
function saveData(url = '', data = {}) {
    return fetch(url).then(response=>response.json()); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to `await` for `response.json()` too.

Try `return await response.json();`, instead of `return response.json();`

Comment: I don't follow your solution, exactly. `async` function should return `Promise` and `saveData` does. I don't see reason to use `await` here (and it does not change the result).

Comment: it's a little wierd that they're awaiting a promise and then returning another promise anyway, but that isn't the issue. if you awaited the response then the code will break later when they call `then` on a non-promise.