# Error creating an empty object literal

Tags: javascript

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input is showing on the Chrome console, the line number leads to this:

```
var A={};
```

Comment: It works fine in my Chrome console.

Comment: This looks correct. What's the line before this line?

Comment: This is the first line

Comment: Can you create a JSFiddle recreating the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks correct. Most probably, the line before the line:

```
var A = {};
```

Should have the issue. And if you try to remove this line, there will be error thrown in the same line again, but it would have a different code. Check for missing semi-colons in the previous line.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is anything wrong with that, try to check the code above it; maybe you're missing a bracket or a semicolon.

Im sure if you remove it, you will still get an error on another line.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when the JS file ends with an unresolved bracket or paren [0], and so the actual fix needs to be applied above the line you posted.

Run a syntax checker like [JSHint](http://www.jshint.com/) against it to find the source of the error.

[0] https://stackoverflow.com/a/3594969/1216976