# Uncaught Type Error in javascript: object has no method

Tags: javascript

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object 0 has no method 'addEventListener' 

var A={};
A.addEventsToClassName=function(event,className,func)
{
    var a=document.getElementsByClassName(className);
    for(var b in a)
        {
            b.addEventListener(event,func,false);
        }
};
```

Object b is meant to be an element object once the function is called later in the code.  How can I prevent this error?

Comment: How's about you upvote/accept on the [question you just asked? ](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22649724/1216976)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `for (var b in a)` will give the property names within `a`, not the actual values; so you need to dererefence `a` when you want to use them.

```
a[b].addEventListener(event, func, false);
```

Also, it's an Array like data structure, so you should iterate it as such:

```
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
    a[i].addEventListener(event, func, false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`b` is not an object nor an element, it is a string (`"0"`). `for...in` [gives you the keys not the value.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

---

Don't use `for(var b in a)` to loop through a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) (it will loop through not only the properties of itself but also the properties inherited from its parent), do this instead:

```
for(var i = 0; i < a.length; a++){
    a[i].addEventListener...
}
```

If you ask why, then take this for example,

```
for(var a in document.querySelectorAll("body")){
    console.log(a);
}

>"0"
>"length"
>"item"
```

You can see that `for...in` does not work in this case since `length` and `item` are not actually in the list but still properties inherited.

Answer (score 0):

The b is probably a index not your object . Perhaps you want write like this:

```
a[b].addEventListener(event,func,false);
```

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 what do you mean the undefined? The a[b] ? The b is index or key in object a , so I think a[b] is defined.

Comment: There is a [`namedItem` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection#Methods) which makes it to throw this error. In `HTMLCollection.namedItem.addEventListener`, `addEventListener` does not exist in `HTMLCollection.namedItem`.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 yeah ,I understand.But we don't know the context and environment , perhaps the addEventListener is exist :-)