# SyntaxError with .js and .css - ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, css, asp.net-mvc

When I load the page I can't show errors but when I use the inspector in Google Chrome I have this **error:**

*`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input`*

**File**: :65200/js/metro.min.js:1

And the **first line** of **metro.min.js** is **all** of **this**:

```
var METRO_AUTO_REINIT, METRO_LOCALE, METRO_WEEK_START, METRO_DIALOG = !1;
(function (c) {
    c.Metro = function (a) {
        c.extend({}, a)
    };
    c.Metro.getDeviceSize = function () {
        return {
            width: 0 < window.innerWidth ? window.innerWidth : screen.width,
            height: 0 < window.innerHeight ? window.innerHeight : screen.height
        }
    }
})(jQuery);
$(function () {
    $("html").on("click", function (c) {
        $(".dropdown-menu").each(function (a, b) {
            $(b).hasClass("keep-open") || "block" != $(b).css("display") || $(b).hide()
        })
    })
});
```

The **.cshtml file** have this:

```
<link href="~/css/metro-bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="~/css/metro-bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="~/css/iconFont.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="~/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

And:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/modernizr-2.7.2.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/metro.min.js"></script>
```

**Why can this be happening?**

I'm using this **bootstrap css:**
http://metroui.org.ua/

And I installed from here with **Package Manager Console**:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Metro.UI.CSS/

Comment: why do you have both jquery's included? Take only the minified version sames goes for UI...

Answer (score 1):

That error usually means you have unclosed `}` brackets ... though they seem ok in the fragment you have supplied though there may be some missing `;` e.g.

```
$(function () {
    $("html").on("click", function (c) {
        $(".dropdown-menu").each(function (a, b) {
            $(b).hasClass("keep-open") || "block" != $(b).css("display") || $(b).hide()
        }); // here
    }); // here
});
```

Comment: Also see these questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3983088/ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3594923/

Comment: There are some links in http://geektnt.com/uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-end-of-input-error-in-chrome.html that may help you find where the missing `}` bracket is - likely lower down in your code.

Comment: When I add the }); appear the error: **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )**

Answer (score 1):

You have included both `jquery-2.1.0.js` and `jquery-2.1.0.min.js`. Either one you can use at a Time.

Same for `jquery-ui-1.10.4.js` and `jquery-ui-1.10.4.min.js` either one you can use it here also.

Remove Min.Js both of the places and use `.Js` version jquery for Run time. While doing deployment include  `min.js` and remove `.js` file.

If you use both of the files you will get continuously `Uncaught SyntaxError` exceptions. Only Include Below Lines under your Script:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/modernizr-2.7.2.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/metro.min.js"></script>
```

And also follow the another answer of **Ruskin** `your function is missing colons at the end of the function.`