# Ajax call returns SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am working on a very simple notepad application.
The user may fetch "a file" (in reality it is just a row from MySQL) to edit it.
When submitting the form directly to the php file ( just remove e.preventDetfault ), the output is the json encoded output I want:

```
{"data":{"filename":"testfile","content":"this is the file content","lastupdate":"2016-03-06 13:13:30"}}
```

However, when ran through the below Ajax call, it always returns **SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input.**

The form

```
<form id="openfile" action="backend.php" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="filename" placeholder="Enter filename to open" id="filename" />
</form>
```

The jQuery AJAX call

```
$("#openfile").submit(function(e) {

  var filename = $("#filename").val();

  openFile(filename);

  e.preventDefault(); 

});


function openFile(filename) {

  if(filename == "") {
    return false;
  }


  $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "backend.php",
         data: {action: "load", file: filename},
         success: function(response) {
         console.log(response);
         },
         error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log("Status: " + textStatus);
            console.log("Error: " + errorThrown);
        }
       });

}
```

The backend

```
      try {

        $db = new PDO(DB_DSN, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
        $sql = "SELECT `filename`, `content`, `lastupdate`
                FROM `notepad`
                WHERE `filename` = :filename
                LIMIT 1";
        $sth = $db->prepare($sql);
        $sth->bindParam(":filename", $_POST['file'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $sth->execute();

        if($sth->rowCount() != 0) {
          $result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
           $response['data'] = $result;
          //echo json_encode($result);
        } else {
          $response['error'] = "File does not exist";
        }

      } catch(PDOException $e) {
        $response['error'] = $e->getMessage();
      }

      // Return json data
      echo json_encode($response);
```

I know for sure the correct data is being sent (chrome dev tools -> network).

Using a nearly identical ajax call to save a file works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is similar to:
[Chrome: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3594923/chrome-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-end-of-input)

Try to add headers `application/json` for your response:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: Forgot to mention that I do have that header included.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried specifying the dataType as Json?

i.e.

**dataType: 'json',**

in your Ajax call.

You're sending back a json object, but you haven't specified the return type.