# Error on getting data from external API

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a `HTML` page with Google ADWords in it, and an `ajax` call from an external URL, and I want to get the `json` data from the url.
The external `API` is also made by me.
The `API Controller` (in `Laravel 5.2`):

```
public function index()
{
    $data = WeatherData::orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->first();

    return Response::json($data);
}
```

HTML ADWords Code:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'https://weather.mnsc.com/api/v1/data',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        cors: true,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
```

But I get an error in Chrome:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://weather.mnsc.com/api/v1/data. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500.

Is there a header I need to set in Laravel API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I find what might be the problem. The problem is with request type.
I switched from `post` to `get` in the `ajax` call, and now it seems to work as expected.

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://weather.mnsc.com/api/v1/data',
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: 'JSON',
  crossDomain: true,
  success: function (data) {
     console.log(data);
  }
});
```

But this doesn't help me, as Google AdWords require only post request...

I also suspect that this is an issue from the Laravel API, there must be something that have to be set in order to use `post` requests.

**UPDATE:**

as I've suspected, the problem in `post` requests is with `Larvael's csrf token.`. I made an workaround by commenting the line in `Kernel.php`.

Answer (score 1):

You need a `crossDomain: true` property for the AJAX request, instead of a normal one. Also, `$.ajax()` doesn't have a `cors` option, so I've removed that. See [`jQuery.ajax()` settings](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings) on the documentation page for all available options:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://weather.mnsc.com/api/v1/data',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: Doesn't he also have to set $.support.cors = true;  ?

Comment: @spozun I'm not sure of that, let me check. I'll update if so

Comment: I've removed cors and add your line, still no fix the problem :(

Comment: @spozun "$.support.cors contains the result of a test that tests whether or not the current browser supports cors. changing it doesn't make the browser support cors."

Comment: @NickBull yes but you can also set it :-)

Comment: @EBuzila Any error output that you can get? Add `error: function(e) { console.log(e); }` as an option to the `$.ajax()` method options.

Comment: @EBuzila Really! That I never knew. I'll look into this, I've never had to do that.

Comment: @Nick Thanks for your effort, i check the error, it return `Object {readyState: 0, responseText: "", status: 0, statusText: "error"}` in the console

Comment: @EBuzila Try this instead, actually: `error: function(xhr, status, error) {
  var err = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
  console.log(err);
}`

Comment: Ok now i'm getting this `VM1342:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input`, plus the previous 'No-Access-Controll' error

Comment: That means your JSON request data is incorrectly formatted somehow - and that's as much as I could tell you. So the answer is that your issue lies in your request JSON formatting. Try `data: JSON.stringify(json),`, to parse the JSON and see if that fixes it up for you. Also check your JSON matches the API request for the server.

Comment: Well if i check the response in a web browser, i get `{"id":1,"status":"800","temperature":"35","created_at":"2016-08-11 00:00:00","updated_at":null}`, which is actually the correct answer, and don't see any syntax errors in the `json` response. I'll check your solution

Comment: Hmm, after a little more research, it could be your JavaScript that's busted, missing a `}` probably. See this SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3594923/chrome-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-end-of-input

Comment: I'll check that post, thanks a lot for all your efforts. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Put this line of code before your ajax call.  I've had to always set this to get cross domain jquery ajax working.

```
$.support.cors = true;
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.support/ - Actually, I think jQuery recommends against this. "Intended for internal use only".