# Chrome extension - Unexpected end of Input

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, syntax

I'm trying to code my first chrome extension, it's supossed to simple autosort for tabs by url name but I'm getting "Unexpected End of Input" at the end of this block of code. It only showed up after I added the listener of onClicked.

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function apllyOrder(tabs) {
    // gets reference array of sorted tabs
    reference = sortTabsUrl(tabs);
    console.log("Reference array loaded");
    // gets amount of pinned tabs to skip them
    pinned = tabsPinned(tabs);
    console.log("Pinned tabs identified");

    //iterates through reference array
    for(var i = 0, len = reference.length; i < len; i++){
    //iterates through tabs starting from first unpinned tabs
    for(var x = pinned, leng = tabs.length; x < leng; x++){
        //If the id matches AND reference index is different than current index than it moves the tab
        if(tabs[x].id == reference[i].id && x != (i +pinned)){
            // tabs is moved based on x(current index) + i(reference index)
            chrome.tabs.move(tabs[x].id, i + x)
        }
    }
}
});
```

My manifest file is this:

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,

"name": "Tab Organizer",
"description": "Auto Organizes Tabs",
"version": "1.0",

"background": {
    "scripts": ["tabOrganizer.js"],
    "persistent": false
},

"permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "<all_urls>"
],
"browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
}
}
```

I imagine I'm making a dumb mistake since I'm new at this but thanks in advance!

Comment: Aren't you missing the function `sortTabsUrl`?

Comment: Also, `apllyOrder` is misspelled, just saying.

Comment: sortTabsURL and applyOrder are defined somewhere else and it wouldn't fit in my post
And thanks! Late night coding made me do some dumb mistakes like misspelling apply

Comment: Have you checked for syntax errors? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3594923/chrome-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-end-of-input

Comment: Probably is missing some function ending `}` or `)`, but maybe in other place in the file.

Comment: You're using a unary plus here `i +pinned`. Add a space after it.